# Proper way to pass around Serializable in Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room, serializable

To save boilerplate, I thought it would be a cool idea to make my Room `Entity` a `Serializable` and pass it around in an `Intent` - but I had a bad feeling in doing this. Surely enough, [this article](https://jacquessmuts.github.io/post/modularization_room/) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56058576/is-it-good-practice-implementing-parcelable-on-a-room-database-entity) advise against doing so.

Thus I made a `Serializable` `data class`, and made it the sole column in the `Entity`. Is this adequately addressing the concerns, or does this not really solve anything at all? Both classes lie in the same module.

#### Vehicle.kt

```
@Entity
data class Vehicle(
    @PrimaryKey val data: VehicleData
)
```

#### VehicleData.kt

```
data class VehicleData(
    val workArea: String,
    val vehicleNumber: String
): Serializable
```

Comment: "or does this not really solve anything at all?" -- it does not address any of the concerns that I raised in [my answer to the SO question that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56058763/115145). I also would not expect that to compile, unless you have a `TypeConverter` that is teaching Room how to store a `VehicleData` in a single column. And, even if you do that, then you basically break your ability to query on each `VehicleData` property (e.g., query for all vehicles in a work area).

Comment: So, you would be better off just making `VehicleData` be the `@Entity`. For trivial projects, particularly solo-developer projects, you can probably get away with having your Room entities be `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and pass them around. I would not recommend that for any serious project, for the reasons that I outlined in that answer.